# EF Core 5, delete a relation many-to-many

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, ef-core-5.0

I have an api powered by **EF Core 5** and I'm working with a many-to-many relationship (**Artists** and **Releases** tables).

The post action works fine even thaugh, for artist for exemple, I decided to not add the possibility to send Guids of already existing releases but only full releases objects that would be created at the same time.

So how am I gonna link artists to already existing releases? I'm trying to do so inside the put action, by sending inside the artistDto a releaseDto list only contening Guids.

This works fine to add new relationships, the ArtistRelease junction table is indeed updated BUT **The Guids I don't specify are not deleted, I can't delete relationships, except if I'm deleting the artist or the release.**

So my question is how can I delete a relationship?

Can you provide me some help please?

```
var releases = Repository.Release.GetReleases(artistForUpdateDto.Releases, trackChanges: false);

if(releases.Count() != artistForUpdateDto.Releases.Count())
{
    Logger.LogInfo($"Some release ids are not valid in the ArtistForUpdateDto object");
    return NotFound();
}

Mapper.Map(artistForUpdateDto, artist);
artist.Releases = releases.ToList();

Repository.Save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution, I just needed to fetch the artist with an "include" to get its releases

```
RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Where(expression).Include(includeExpression)
```

If I save the artist with an empty list, the join table will be updated :)